# Graph associated to a vector matrix, is there such a notion?

Tags: graph-theory

Given a $k\times k$ matrix with entries from $\{0,1\}$ and diagonal entries $0$ one can associate a simple directed graph to it. ([See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix))

I was wondering if such a notion were possible for a matrix with vector entries?

Consider for example consider the matrix
$$A=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a_{1,1}^1 & \cdots & a_{1,n_1}^1 & \cdots & a_{1,1}^k & \cdots & a_{1,n_k}^k\\
  \vdots & ~ & \vdots & ~ & \vdots & ~ & \vdots \\
  a_{k,1}^1 & \cdots & a_{k,n_1}^1 & \cdots & a_{k,1}^k & \cdots & a_{k,n_k}^k  
 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{a}_1^1& \cdots & \mathbf a_1^k\\
\vdots  & ~ &\vdots\\
\mathbf a_k^1 & \cdots & \mathbf a_k^k
\end{pmatrix}$$

which is a $k\times k$ vector matrix with $a_{i,j}^l\in\{0.1\}$ and the diagonal vectors $\mathbf a_i^i=\mathbf 0$ , where $\mathbf 0$ is the zero vector of appropriate size. Can I now associate a graph to this? I considered a graph with $k$ vertices and with directed edge from $i$th to $j$th vertex of wieght the modulus of the vector. This however does not differentiate between two vectors of same modulus. So is there any way to associate a graph to $A$ so that I can recover $A$ as a vector matrix (upto some permutation of its rows and columns) just by looking at the graph?

Thank you.

Comment: The most natural generalization to me would be to associate a matrix of binary $n$-vectors with a family of $n$ graphs, rather than a single graph.

Comment: If the vectors in your $k \times k$ vector matrix also have dimension $k$, you could view this as a $3$-regular hypergraph.

Comment: Another solution is to represent your vector matrix as several ordinary matrices, and draw them all on the same graph but with different colored edges (note that this would produce a multigraph).

Comment: Of course there are always unnatural ways of embedding any structure into a graph; I assume your question is about any 'natural' way to associate a unique graph with this structure, perhaps in a one-to-one way.

Comment: @BobKrueger Yes that is what I am looking for. A 'natural' one-to-one way. Could you give me a good reference from which I can learn about hypergraphs? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not really good with references, but any suitably-advanced book on graph theory (or explicitly mentioning hypergraphs) would be good. Try Berge or Deistel.